# :APEX MD5 32-bit uppercase

Tags: apex

**Sample code**

```
Long dataGMT = System.now().getTime() / 1000;
system.debug('dataGMT = ' + dataGMT);
String token = 'Q1' + dataGMT + 'Q2';
system.debug('token = ' + token);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'MD5Hash(token) === ' + MD5Hash(token));
public static String MD5Hash(String value) {
    return hash('MD5', value);
}

public static String hash(String algorithmName, String input) {
    return EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf(input)));
}
```

**How to get 32-bit uppercase?**

The result of the sample code is 32-bit lowercase.

**result :** d06f11aa4627092e03400fc27ab09908 ---(32-bit lowercase)

**Expected result** :
D06F11AA4627092E03400FC27AB09908  ---(32-bit uppercase)

Comment: [String toUpperCase](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_toUpperCase) can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you use `MD5Hash(token).toUpperCase()`.

`toUpperCase` is a method in String which converts your string value to upper case.